# Where can I download PostgreSQL 8.0.2 windows installer binary?

Tags: windows, postgresql

For development purpose I need to install PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on my development PC but I can't find PostgreSQL 8.0.2 Windows installer. I searched here http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/binary/v8.0.20/ but only the linux version is here.

Comment: 8.0? really? I don't think there is any official site that offers such an outdated and un-supported version any more. You will probably need to download the sources and compile them yourself.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you really want a database full of bugs and security problems for new development work? Support stopped in October 2010, it's dead.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/78222/where-can-i-download-postgresql-8-0-windows-binary-files

Comment: @FrankHeikens: probably an Amazon Redshift user - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to install PostgreSQL 8.0.anything, let alone 8.0.2. If you truly needed 8.0, you should install 8.0.26, the last bugfix release before 8.0.x was discontinued from support. The only purpose I can imagine for installing it is to read a data directory created with 8.0 that wasn't backed up any other way, so you can dump it and restore to a current version.

Comment: @Denis Good guess, especially given the specific mention of 8.0.2. Trying to install 8.0.2 as a Redshift substitute is crazy talk though, so if that's the user's goal the answer is "don't". As you probably know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you not to use an old version like that, but I understand develop circumstances.

Digging deeper, I found that only version from 8.2 where official for windows.

Probably there was a notice in download page, now you find only post about it like: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200909150821.n8F8L4eV025668@wwwmaster.postgresql.org

I can say that probably your problem to solve does not come from a windows version. Am I right? Now, if you develop on windows I suggest to build a running Postgresql from sources on a virtual machine.

Comment: Actually 8.0 (not 8.2) was the first version with official Windows support: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/release-8-0.html

Answer (score 1):

You can [download PostgreSQL 8.4.4 by clicking here](http://downloadofflineinstaller.com/download_postgresql_8.4.4_id_7474).

Comment: Latest Version http://downloadofflineinstaller.com/download_postgresql_9.6.0_id_18514

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this link](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows) for new versions and use [this link](http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/postgresql/8.0.22#package_detail_tabs) for 8.0.2 version. it also contains `pgadmin` tool for graphical interface of the database.

Comment: There is no 8.0 version on that page.

Comment: Those are Version 8.4.xx

Comment: you can use also [this link] (http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/postgresql/8.0.15)

Comment: All are linux installer. and i need 8.0.2 windows installer not 8.0.15

Comment: Well than you can use 8.0.15 version on windows or make a separate install of 8.0.2 on a linux machine so that it will take the load of all database activities.